# How to let 2 Nodejs processes communicate with a JWT authentication server

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have 2 Node JS apps running on the same server on different ports.
Now i want to add an authentication server which handles JWT authentication with all clients from both apps.

So client1 could log in through app1 which would send the log in request to the authentication server. The auth server would do its stuff and send back a JWT to app1 which sends it to the client and grants him access to some stuff. Now the client could also go to app2 send his JWT and app2 again would forward it to the auth server which would check if its valid and let app2 know so it can grant access to the user too.

I already have the JWT authentication done. I only need the part where app1 or app2 forward the login to the auth server and it tells app1 or app2 if the user is granted access.

What would be the best approach to this?
Should i use

- a pub-sub system like node-ipc
- API routes (would be stupid because all apps run on the same server)
- websockets
- something else

I have been researching a lot but there are too many different ways which either seem overkill or wouldn't work quite the way i wanted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: API routes is by far the simplest way to achieve your goal. And I doubt it's a stupid choice. They may run on the same server now but may not to in a few months time. IPC is way to low for your requirements.

Comment: Hmm okay. Yeah you are right it would also be future proof.

Comment: Is the JWT signed with a preshared key or an assymetric algorithm? If the former, do both app1 and app2 use the same preshared key or a different one? Also, is your JWT issuing based on OIDC or are you crafting a custom protocol?

Comment: app1 and app2 don't use a key at all, because the auth server handles all that. So they both use the same one in a sense. Currently i am only using the jsonwebtoken library not oauth2 or sth.

Comment: @creerow: sounds like you are reinventing SSO by passing the token between apps which is totally not needed if both apps follow OpenIDConnect against the same auth server. Be warned that reinventing SSO makes you incompatible with anyone else, you basically create your own reality and if you are ever to build a compound system made of yours components are some other components based on established protocols, you have extra work to do.

Comment: @creerow: on the other hand, if you share the very same way of signing your token, you don't have to pass it anywhere as the **very same** token can be used between multiple apps. It's just when your browser has the token, the browser sends in to any api in any app.